# PHP SQLite3 WAL - is close() required for each opened database connection even if it is the same?

Tags: php, sqlite, wal

Windows 10, PHP 7, SQLite3 database in wal mode, JQuery. JQuery ajax response is very slow, and entering and changing values in a field on web page results in the values showing/changing every 1 - 3 seconds until the last given value is shown, and also in the database. The JQuery ajax is fired on onblur, and after a value is entered I move out from the field, and then back again to enter a new value, then out and back, etc.

The wal file is growing all of the time, being something like 16 MB (the database file itself is like 2 MB), and as I suppose both files (db and wal) are read for a request the size of the wal file makes things slow. Or?

Data (not the same data, but using a connection with the same handle name) is read and written to/from the db sequentially from multiple PHP scripts from multiple users from multiple workstations using the same handle name, like $db_data=new SQLite3("path/to/file.db");, for ex. a script or function asks for data and starts with $db_data=new SQLite3("path/to/file.db"); and then $v1=$dbh_data->query("...)", and another script or function writes data with $db_data=new SQLite3("path/to/file.db"); and then $q1=$dbh_data->exec("...");.

In order for the wal file to be of size 0 or otherwise very small when a thing has run I have read that I should close() all connections to the database (not having anything reading or writing to the database) to allow for the wal file content to commit into the actual database. This close() is, of course, something I did not write into the scripts/functions back then. For now, if nothing is going on, the wal file stays at something like 16 MB.

Do I have to explicitly do a close() in all functions and scripts where I have "$db_data=new SQLite3("path/to/file.db");", or is there a way to do a forced "master" or "global" close() for a database connection once and for all to allow for the wal stuff to go into the db?

Comment: You should always close a database connection when done so that sqlite can gracefully clean up journal files etc., yes.

Comment: But see https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_wal_checkpoint to force a checkpoint.

Comment: @Shawn, now I know that I should always close a connection, but not back then. I also have read about PRAGMAs, and have implemented this (wal_autocheckpoint). But the problem remains, the wal file is there, I suppose it will be around until all connections are closed, if there is no "master" way of closing all connections to a database.